# How to index a huge amount of data quickly via ElasticSearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, bigdata

I have 3TB data, about 10Billion records, every record has 6 columns such as: `name,location,ip,count,behavior,type.`
I have 10 linux servers, each server has 16 cores, 90G memory and 5TB hard disk space.

I wan't to finish the indexing very quickly, so how should I design the ElasticSearch index structure please, such as: How many shards would be better? and, should I use multiple types, i.e the same index has multiple types. Is multiple types helpful for the indexing performance please.

Comment: Here are some good reads: http://cpratt.co/how-many-shards-should-elasticsearch-indexes-have/ and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html (to emphasize replicas serve requests!).  As to how you should organize the data into indices and mappings really depends on your plans for the data and what the data is.

Comment: For good practice, you'll need to benchmark your cluster and index configuration performance, there is no magic recipes for that. I invited you to read this [blog entry](http://dstoolbox.blogspot.fr/2015/09/basic-elasticsearch-load-testing-with.html) concerning load testing elasticsearch along with the links recommended in the earlier comment. Nevertheless, this question remains quite broad!

Comment: Hi Guys, I found if I used multiple types under same index, then indexing speed would be faster than only one type. for example I created an index called testIndex, if indexing 3TB data under /testIndex/type1 which would take 20 hours, while indexing 3TB data under /testIndex/type1, /testIndex/type2 and /testIndex/type3 respectively with only 1TB data each type, the indexing time only took 7 hours. What do you guys think of this please :)

Comment: 1TB per index is quite an amount of data. Make sure you take special attention to how many shards you give to your index. It's easy to index data, but issues are bound to occur when you start searching your data, memory will definitely be an issue. So if you don't have enough nodes to spread your load, you'll get into trouble, and in order to be able to scale horizontally on several nodes, you need to have enough shards in your index.

Comment: @Jack did you find a solution?

Comment: @Sam, Maybe, I increased the bulk thread size and queue size. Also I set a proper bulk size number.